# Using Python to slice an audio file into timeline subtitle, based on the transcripts

Tags: python, audio, subtitle

Input:

```
-Audio.mp3 (Someone saying:"Hello world,I'm happy")
-Transcript.txt (text:"Hello world,I'm happy")
```

Output:

```
-Timeline.srt (00:01~00:02-"Hello world", 00:03~00:04"I'm happy")
```

I've googled, slacked, and try to use "pydub" to slice audio, but all base on a fixed segment.

How can I slice the audio base on the scripts that already exist?

Comment: Does the transcript include timestamps? If not, I'm not sure how any tool could output the timeline you'd want (unless it'd be doing some speech analysis for you).

Comment: The transcript did not include any timestamps.

Yes, I think the speech analysis is what I need, thank you for providing me a thouht. The audio file is mandarin, so I probably need a mandarin speech to text tool.